# Excel enter cell value from a list

Tags: excel-2010

I have a budget spreadsheet for simple money transactions.  One of the columns is the transaction category (e.g. Grocery, Auto Supplies, Insurance, Entertainment, etc.)

Rather than spell out, let's say, Insurance, in a given cell, I would like a list of possible values to appear, so that I can select one of the values (e.g., Insurance) and have Excel put that value in the cell for me.  That way I make sure that Insurance is spelled the same each time I use it.

Is there an easy way to set this up in my workbook, preferably without getting into VBA coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dropdown lists in Excel. What I found from [this video](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2#ID0EAABAAA=Transcript):

"
Select the cells that you want to contain the lists. On the ribbon, click the DATA tab, and click Data Validation. In the dialog, set Allow to List. Click in Source. In this example, we are using a comma-delimited list. The text or numbers we type in the Source field are separated by commas. And click OK. The cells now have a drop-down list.
"

Comment: Thanks much.  This was the direction I needed.  I didn't view the video which might have shown how to put the list in a table.  But with a little digging I found that in the Source field you can put "=" followed by a range reference.  I chose to list my categories on another sheet, give that range a name of Categories, then put =Categories in the validation Source field.  Works great!